# How can I find the volume of the solid generated with the given information?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Here is the question:

Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the regions bounded by the graphs of the equation about the y-axis.

Given: y=$\sqrt{x}$; $y=0$; $x=3$

Here are the steps I took to get the (wrong) answer:

1. Area = $\pi \times (y^2)^2 = \pi \times y^4$
2. $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}(\pi y^4) dy$
3. After evaluating this definite integral, I got $9{\pi} \sqrt{3}$ all over 5.

Can you please help me figure out where I made my mistake or if I took the wrong approach?
Thank you.

Comment: You rotated the area between the curve and the y axis when you should have rotated the area between the curve and the x axis.

Comment: The question stated that I must find the volume of the solid generated when revolved around the y-axis, so would I have to rotate it between the curve and the x-axis?

Comment: ...that statement doesn't make sense. When we say we rotate around something, we specify an axis of rotation which must always be a line. I didn't say your axis of rotation was wrong, but the area you are rotating is wrong.

Comment: Do you know what's the correct answer? I got $\frac{36\sqrt3\pi}5$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That is the correct answer.

Comment: I got it using the same idea from the comment by @NinadMunshi.

Comment: In my work, I intended to rotate it between the curve and the x-axis, but I believe my steps were wrong. How can I fix my work to have the equation be rotated between the curve and the x-axis?

Comment: @NinadMunshi you're right, I misread both what the OP wrote and what you originally wrote, I have removed my comments

Comment: Visualize what is being rotated and ask yourself if the cross sections are discs or washers (discs with holes in them)

Comment: @NinadMunshi I realized that I should be using the washer method. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This region:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is one of two congruent finite area regions that have edges on all three bounding curves.  (The other one is mirror symmetric below the $x$-axis and has the same volume of revolution.)

This is a horizontally simple region.  You should be able to find the volume of revolution (about the $y$-axis) using
$$  \pi \int_0^\sqrt{3} (3)^2 - (\text{something})^2 \,\mathrm{d}y  \text{,}  $$